# Error when upgrading to vs 4.6.8

Tags: upgrade

My work partner and I were trying to upgrade Civi from vs 4.5 to 4.6.8 and got an error that we couldn't figure out. We are using Wordpress. Here's a screen shot of the error message we got: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XEd5SqrbFbgwzHFBRG1oW3UMZLX_YtuizroLPLjvViI/edit
Can anyone help me with this? We are not even sure what it means (I have to note here that I'm not very knowledgable about code). Even though we got this error I was still able to login to Civi and see all my data, but I'm nervous that something might be wrong that I can't see yet. Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks,
Lauren

Comment: Can't access the doc - can you change its sharing to 'Anyone with the link'?

Comment: The screenshot shows that table civicrm_action_mapping does not exist in a SQL select query.

Answer (score 2):

That table is involved in reminders, and was introduced in CiviCRM 3.4, so there is a serious issue with your database. I recommend restoring a backup of your site and database (you have those, right?) and trying the upgrade again. Please note the first errors you get, as those are often most useful in diagnosing what is going wrong, rather than later more serious messages.

It would likely be a good idea to verify that the table is in your backup before starting the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I do have a backup. I will make sure I more completely capture the errors if I have any next time. We don't use reminders currently. If the table was missing, wouldn't it be inserted during the install/upgrade? Please forgive me, my technical knowledge is very limited but I am eager to learn!

Comment: No, the upgrade code is not designed to diagnose and fix serious database corruption problems. Best of luck!

Comment: Please post a separate question if you find the table is not present in your backup. My sense is that you will need professional help at that point.